# Get TFS server details associated with a file

Tags: c#, .net

I have a file which is under a TFS source control.

Is there any way to get the associated TFS details, if we have full access to that file.

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain further what it is that you're trying to get? What kind of TFS details?

Comment: What environment?  Is it programmatic?  Would a command-line result do (the tf command comes to mind, or I believe that there is a powershell plugin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get to a workspace from the file (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/628106/67392)). Once you have that, and thus the server you can easily get an instance of `VersionControlServer` with its [`GetItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb138919.aspx) method (using either server or client path) to get an instance of [`Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.item.aspx) which contains all the TFS details of the file or folder.

Answer (score 0):

TFS has a robust API available. [Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130331.aspx#versioncontrolserver) an example of using it, although you may want to start with [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what details you are trying to get.  In Source Control Explorer you can right-click the file and select properties.  Also, from the command line you can run "tf.exe properties " to get more information.